# How much have I spent in real money on Roblox

Tags: roblox

Roblox seem to want to hide away how much I've spent (paid) on the game, or, I do not understand how to traverse the maze of menus.

I am trying to learn how much I've spent on both of my daughters.

I log into Roblox in my browser, and I click on the Robux symbol. A drop list opens, and I choose the first option (which shows how many Robux remain). This has taken me into My Transactions.

[image]

If I review summary, current purchases or purchases, it shows the total number of Robux (which is the name of the currency in the game) I have bought. I do not see how much real money I have spent (in USD$ or GBP£).

I can't simply use email receipts because there is no way to know which of my daughters each receipt is for.

Is it possible to get this?

Comment: Can't you just check your credit/debit card transactions to see it?

Comment: I can - but I think every online service I have allows me to see my billing history. I don't think I should have to rely on my email client to be able to sort and group to see my purchase history for a given product

Answer (score 3):

According to a Robux to USD website converter I managed to find [here](https://sponsorhunter.com/calculators/robux-to-usd-calculator/), **you have spent roughly $56.25** of USD on Roblox, due to a constant rate of one Robux being worth $0.0125.

Comment: The problem with this is that there *isn't* a constant Robux-to-USD (or any other real world currency) conversion rate: there are various volume discounts, and occasionally they have a sale.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can really do this, but I have two options:
Make some math and then translate that number (Robux) to USD.
**Otherwise**
you can install [BTRoblox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/btroblox-making-roblox-be/hbkpclpemjeibhioopcebchdmohaieln) that can help you to translate faster Robux to USD. You first should enable that setting in the main menu, though.

Answer (score -2):

When you buy robux, it shows you how much it costs. Just add it up. I bought robux before, and it shows how much it costs.